# Vue: Component :prop="object[key]" aren't reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to bind a value from an `Object` into the prop of a Component, but it isn't reactive. I'm even using `$this.set`, but it doesn't work at all. Here's my template:

```
<div class="grid">
  <emoji-card v-for="name in shuffledEmoji"
    :name="name" :ticked="tickedEmoji[name]" :key="name"      
    @click="tickEmoji(name)"
  />
</div>
```

- `shuffledEmoji`: `Array<String>`

Here, `tickedEmoji` is an Object with keys being strings, and values being `Boolean`s. `tickEmoji` just sets `tickedEmoji[name]` for that name to be `true`:

```
  methods: {
    tickEmoji (name) {
      this.$set(this.tickedEmoji, name, true)
    }
  },
```

That method gets called fine, but the Component doesn't notice the changes.

Child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="card" @click="$emit('click')">
    <img draggable="false" :src="`/static/blobs/${name}.png`">
    <img v-show="ticked" class="green-tick" draggable="false"
      src="/static/ui/green_tick.png">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'emoji-card',
  props: ['name', 'ticked']
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here? The child component never gets updated whenever `tickEmoji` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, removing this initialization code in my `beforeCreate` fixed it. If someone could provide some insight on why this is the case, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
  async beforeCreate () {
    let {blobs} = await (await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/blobs')).json()

    // init tickedEmoji map (fixes code when this loop is removed)
    for (let key of blobs) {
      this.tickedEmoji[key] = false
    }

    this.emoji = blobs
  }
```

Comment: This is where you need to use $set. Adding the properties dynamically in this fashion means they are [not converted in to observed values](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Comment: @slice The `beforeCreate` function called synchronously after the component instance has just been initialized, before data observation and event/watcher setup.You change it a `async` function, and init tickedEmoji map await for the request to be responsed, but the component's lifecycle will not await, so the component will not know the tickedEmoji.